# Creating Forms with Conditional Logic that Leads to Different Pages within Shopify

Tags: forms, shopify

I'd like to create a form page that leads to different pages depending on if a person selects yes or no to a question. I am putting together a registration for different education courses depending on if they have taken a prior course before. Is this possible to do with just custom liquid theme templates and basic Javascript?

Example:
Have you taken this course?

Yes => Form 1 => Cart Payment and Summary

No => Form 2

These forms will ask for custom information about the customer and depending on if they answer yes or no they will be able to purchase tickets to the course.

Comment: Use any custom 3rd party form like google form or wufoo forms.

Comment: will wufoo work with shopify payments?

Comment: Nopes, they don't. for Shopify payments, you need to check advance product options.

Comment: what would be the best way to integrate this form into Shopify's checkout system?

Comment: I think a custom app will work in this case.

Comment: So I'd have to build one out myself? I am familiar with React / Node.js